# Set the total number of pages and change the number of records on each page dynamically in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to set the total number of pages and length of each page in a datatable based on an array. The length of the array should be the number of pages in the datatable and the number of records in each page should be the value of elements of the array.

```
var pageLenArr = [10,13,15,19,25,35,60];

 $('#result').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
            
            var info = table.page.info();
            var currentPage = info.page;
            var pageLength ='';
            
            for (var i = 0; i< pageLenArr.length; i++){
                if(currentPage ==i){
                    table.page.len(pageLenArr[i]).draw();
                }
            }
            
        });
```

So here the total number of pages in the datatable should be 7 i.e. length of "pageLenArr". Page 1 should contain 10 records, Page 2 should contain 13 records, Page 3 should contain 15 records and so on i.e., elements of the array are the number of records for each page.

Comment: Is not clear what you're asking. What is `table` ? What is with the `jsp` tag ? How about the `datatable` tag ? Did you meant to use [`datatables`](https://datatables.net/) which is the jQuery plugin ?

Comment: Yes I am about datatables jquery plugin